# Multiple plots on same figure

Tags: matlab, plot

```
x = [0.35, 0.65, 0.8, 1]
y1 = [0.1, 0.21, 0.29, 0.35]
y2 = [0.11, 0.26, 0.28, 0.39]
y3 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.28, 0.36]
y4 = [0.1, 0.25, 0.31, 0.37]
```

I need to plot all this data on the same graph, such that there is one x-axis and two y-axes, one on the left and one on the right. The interval for y-axes is `0.1:0.1:0.4`, and that for x-axis is `0:0.1:1`.

I have tried `plotyy`:

```
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(x, y2, x, y4);
hold on
[bx, h3, h4] = plotyy(x, y3, x, y1);
```

but one of the vectors does not plot on the same graph. When you run this, and use the PAN option on the graph, you'll realize that only 3 curves are plotted while the 4<sup>th</sup> curve is plotted on another figure. When I check the legend U get only 3 curves, and not 4.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this:

```
plot(x, [y1(:) y2(:) y3(:) y4(:)])
legend({'y1' 'y2' 'y3' 'y4'}, 'Location','NorthWest')
set(gca, 'XLim',[0 1], 'YLim',[0.1 0.4])
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you could do that with `plotyy(x, [y1(:) y2(:)], x, [y3(:) y4(:)])`. But since all your y data have the same scale, why use more than one axis...

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `hold` and use

```
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(x, [y2;y3], x, [y4;y1]);
```

**Edit:**
This is kind of a hack since it is does not support data sets were x differ. That is `y2` and `y3` should be specified for the same `x`. The same is true for `y4` and `y1`.